# How to get all integers between two float values?

Tags: python

I want to get all the integers which are between two float values.
Example:
I have an interval `(2.4 , 5.6)`. As an output I want to have `(3, 4, 5)`.

Is there any function that does this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
import math
list(range(math.ceil(num1), math.floor(num2) + 1))
```